# magento 2 Unable To get Product Attribute

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, plugin

I am trying to fetch product attribute on cart page but it is giving me a null value below is my code

**path:-V\M\Plugin;**

```
class GetAllRates{
    protected $_logger;
    protected $cart;
    private $productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    )
    {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function afterGetAllRates($subject, $result)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/templog.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        
        foreach ($result as $key => $rate) {
            $price = $rate->getCost();
           // $logger->info("cost".json_encode($price)); //log print

            $carrier = $rate->getCarrier();
            $price2 = $rate->getPrice();
           // $logger->info("price".json_encode($price2)); //log print
            
            //changing price fedexseconddaydelivery
            if($carrier == 'fedexseconddaydelivery'){
                if($rate->getCost()==$rate->getPrice()){
                    $shippingCost= 550 + $price;
                    $rate->setPrice($shippingCost);
                    
                }
            }
     
            if ($rate->getIsDisabled()) {
                unset($result[$key]);
            }   
        }
        
        $cart = $this->cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
        foreach($cart as $item) {
            echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
            echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
            echo 'Price: '.$item->getFixedShippingCost().'<br />';

            $myVar = $item->getSku();
            $logger->info("sku".json_encode($myVar));
            $myVar2 = $item->getProductId();
            $logger->info("productid".json_encode($myVar2));
            $fixedShippingCost = $item->getFixedShippingCost();
            $logger->info("fixedshippingcost".json_encode($fixedShippingCost));
        }


        return $result;
    }
}
```

> 2021-09-14T10:43:43+00:00 INFO (6): sku"test1"
> 2021-09-14T10:43:43+00:00 INFO (6): productid"8089"
> 2021-09-14T10:43:43+00:00 INFO (6): fixedshippingcostnull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load product by id

```
private $quoteItemFactory;
private $itemResourceModel;
public function __construct(
  .....
  \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\ItemFactory $quoteItemFactory,
  \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item $itemResourceModel
  ......
) {
   ....
   $this->quoteItemFactory = $quoteItemFactory;
   $this->itemResourceModel = $itemResourceModel;
   ...
}
```

and in one of the methods you can do this:

```
$itemId = $item->getProductId();
$quoteItem = $this->quoteItemFactory->create();
$this->itemResourceModel->load($quoteItem, $itemId);
```

Comment: $itemId or product id; can you be more specific

Comment: updated answer.

Comment: small update you missed a collon while creating object please update it

Comment: may i use it something like this :0----- $itemId = $item->getProductId();
        $quoteItem = $this->quoteItemFactory->create();
        $MyVar = $this->itemResourceModel->load($quoteItem, $itemId);

        $productTest = $MyVar->getName(); // i am trying to get product name here

Comment: yes you can use like that

Comment: not working bro

Comment: change $itemId = $item->getProductId(); to $itemId = $item->getId();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129603/discussion-between-pramod-and-gohil-rajesh).